How to form $x$ sets each from $n$ elements that are from $n$ sets
I need help with a combinatorics problem. There are $n$ non-empty disjoint sets $A_1, \dots, A_n$ with $a_1 \dots, a_n$ elements. All of the sets have at least $x$ elements. We need to find the number $y$ of all possible sets so that each contains exactly $x$ sets of exactly $n$ elements and that each of these $x$ sets includes exactly one element from each of the sets $A_1, \dots, A_n$.
For example: Imagine there are four tables in a restaurant, $t_1$ guests sit at the first table, at the second table $t_2$ guests, and so on. How many ways are there to form $x$ groups of $4$ guests to leave the restaurant, given that all of the tables have at least $x$ guests and every group is composed of one guest from each table? The $x$ groups must be distinct, i.e., $4 x$ different people will always leave the restaurant.
If we were to compose all possible sets of $x$ pairs from two sets $A, B$ of $a, b$ elements and $a, b \ge x$, the formula would be:
$$y = \binom{a}{x} \binom{b}{x} x!$$
However the case with more than two elements appear to be considerably more challenging, however I suppose it has to include the product:$$\binom{a_1}{x} \dots \binom{a_n}{x}$$
Thank you for your help, it is much appreciated :)

Just to clarify, the sets $A_1, \dots, A_n$ are disjoint, correct?

correct, just as the guests in the restaurant are different individuals

This should be relatively straightforward with constructive counting.
First, select the $x$ people from each group that are going to exit. As you have pointed out, this is simply given by $\binom{a_1}{x} \cdots \binom{a_n}{x}$.
Once this is done, we now have to "group up" the selected people by picking one from each group. This is also easy to do: line up each of the $x$ people in each of the $n$ groups, and successively take from the front of the line. There are $(x!)^n$ ways to do this. But be careful! We don't care about the order in which the groups exit. We can easily correct for this by dividing the result by $x!$.
So, the desired count is
$$\binom{a_1}{x} \cdots \binom{a_n}{x} (x!)^{n - 1}$$
